# Why is my Sudoku Solving Python code running so slow using the same logic as a faster code?

Tags: python, sudoku

I made a sudoku solving code in python, closely following the solution given on [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sudoku-backtracking-7/), but my code runs really slowly, albeit producing correct results.

It took over 2 minutes to run, whereas the GeeksForGeeks code took under a second to solve 2 such Sudokus:

My Code:

```py
import time
def printgrid(grid):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            print(grid[i][j], end=' ')
        print("")

def checkLocation(grid,x,y,val):
    if val in grid[x]:
        #print("x"+str(grid[x]))
        return False
    elif True in [val == grid[i][y] for i in range(9)]:
        #print("y"+str(grid[:][y]))
        return False
    return True

def checkGrid(grid):
    if True in [0 in grid[i] for i in range(9)]:
        #print("grid has empty spots")
        return False
    rowmap = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0}
    colmap = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0}
    squmap = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0}
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if rowmap[grid[i][j]] == 0:
                rowmap[grid[i][j]] = 1
            else:
                return False
            if colmap[grid[j][i]] == 0:
                colmap[grid[j][i]] = 1
            else:
                return False
        rowmap = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0}
        colmap = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0}
    for i in [0,3,6]:
        for j in [0,3,6]:
            for tx in [0,1,2]:
                for ty in [0,1,2]:
                    if squmap[grid[i+tx][j+ty]] == 0:
                        squmap[grid[i+tx][j+ty]] = 1
                    else:
                        return False
            squmap = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,7:0,8:0,9:0}
    return True

def solveSudoku(grid):
    if checkGrid(grid):
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if grid[i][j]!=0:
                    continue
                else:
                    for k in range(1,10):
                        if checkLocation(grid,i,j,k):
                            #print("Tried "+str(k))
                            grid[i][j] = k
                            #print(grid)
                            if solveSudoku(grid):
                                return True
                            grid[i][j] = 0
                    return False

mydoku = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
            [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0], 
            [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0], 
            [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3], 
            [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1], 
            [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6], 
            [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0], 
            [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5], 
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]

codoku = [[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
            [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8], 
            [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7], 
            [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3], 
            [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1], 
            [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6], 
            [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4], 
            [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5], 
            [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]]

print(checkLocation(mydoku,1,1,2))
print(checkGrid(codoku))

#print(checkLocation(codoku,8,8,9))

#print(solveSudoku(codoku))
#printgrid(codoku)
#print(checkLocation(mydoku,0,3,6))

start = time.time()
print(solveSudoku(mydoku))
printgrid(mydoku)
diff = time.time() - start

print(diff)
```

Output:

```
True
True
5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2
6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8
1 9 8 3 4 2 5 6 7
8 5 9 7 6 1 4 2 3
4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1
7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6
9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4
2 8 7 4 1 9 6 3 5
3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9
135.41240525245667
```

GeeksForGeeks Code: (comments removed)

```py
import time
def print_grid(arr):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            print(arr[i][j], end=' ')
        print("")
 
         
def find_empty_location(arr, l):
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            if(arr[row][col]== 0):
                l[0]= row
                l[1]= col
                return True
    return False
 
def used_in_row(arr, row, num):
    for i in range(9):
        if(arr[row][i] == num):
            return True
    return False
 
def used_in_col(arr, col, num):
    for i in range(9):
        if(arr[i][col] == num):
            return True
    return False
 
def used_in_box(arr, row, col, num):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if(arr[i + row][j + col] == num):
                return True
    return False
 
def check_location_is_safe(arr, row, col, num):
     
    return not used_in_row(arr, row, num) and not used_in_col(arr, col, num) and not used_in_box(arr, row - row % 3, col - col % 3, num)
 
def solve_sudoku(arr):
     
    l =[0, 0]
     
    if(not find_empty_location(arr, l)):
        return True
     
    row = l[0]
    col = l[1]
     
    for num in range(1, 10):
         
        if(check_location_is_safe(arr,
                          row, col, num)):
             
            arr[row][col]= num
 
            if(solve_sudoku(arr)):
                return True
 
            arr[row][col] = 0
             
    return False
 
if __name__=="__main__":
     
    grid =[[0 for x in range(9)]for y in range(9)]
     
    grid =[[3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0],
          [5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
          [0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0],
          [9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5],
          [0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0],
          [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4],
          [0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0]]
     
    start = time.time()
    if(solve_sudoku(grid)):
        print_grid(grid)
    else:
        print("No solution exists")
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
    mydoku = [["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
            ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
            [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
            ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
            ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
            ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
            [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
            [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
            [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]

    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if mydoku[i][j] == '.':
                mydoku[i][j] = 0
            else:
                mydoku[i][j] = int(mydoku[i][j])

    print("")

    start = time.time()
    if solve_sudoku(mydoku):
        print_grid(mydoku)
    else:
        print("No Solution Exists")
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
```

Output:

```
3 1 6 5 7 8 4 9 2 
5 2 9 1 3 4 7 6 8 
4 8 7 6 2 9 5 3 1
2 6 3 4 1 5 9 8 7
9 7 4 8 6 3 1 2 5
8 5 1 7 9 2 6 4 3
1 3 8 9 4 7 2 5 6
6 9 2 3 5 1 8 7 4
7 4 5 2 8 6 3 1 9
0.013003110885620117

5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2 
6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8 
1 9 8 3 4 2 5 6 7
8 5 9 7 6 1 4 2 3
4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1
7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6
9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4
2 8 7 4 1 9 6 3 5
3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9
0.05815267562866211
```

What is wrong with my code/coding style that my code takes so much more time?
Please help

Comment: `if True in [x for y]` would be more efficiently written as `if any(x for y)`

Comment: Adding that right away, wasn't aware. Edit: Just completed running, time is not much better, although down by a few seconds. New time: 132.64531707763672

Comment: also use `for x in iterable:` instead `for index in range(len(iterable)):`

Comment: @Matiiss how and why does that make it faster? It also isn't compatible with my method in a few places since I interchanged i and j to compute both col and row with 1 for loop

Comment: you can read this article here: https://betterprogramming.pub/stop-using-range-in-your-python-for-loops-53c04593f936 (I think there was a good SO question about this but I couldn't find it), but basically (some points seemingly not included in the article) using `for x in iterable:` goes directly over elements in the list (calling `__next__`), it does the iterating part internally (which is faster), using indices means that first of you need to create the range, then iterate over that, then it has to lookup `__getitem__` and then it gives you the value

Comment: I added a  global counter and saw that `solveSudoku` method is being called more than a million times in your code, whereas 5k times in CodeGeek code. Something is wrong with your recursion, I think. Time taken for each `return False` was 0.0005sec which seems same for both code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the GeekForGeeks version, the `solveSudoku` function solves for only one location (using `find_empty_location`), it picks the first zero value location it encounters and then iterates to find a matching number, where each interaction recursive calls the `solve sudoku` function.

In your code, `solveSudoku` is solving for all locations and the recursive call to `solveSudoku` is made inside nested loops

```
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if grid[i][j]!=0:
                    continue
                else:
                    for k in range(1,10):
                        ... solveSudoku(grid) ...
```

When a recursive call is made, that does not mean the current call is forgotten, and that the function execution starts afresh; the control will eventually come back, that means it is unnecessarily solving for the same location multiple times. I hope that makes sense.

Rewrite this way, it'll run in less than 3 seconds:

```
import time


def printgrid(grid):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            print(grid[i][j], end=' ')
        print("")


def checkLocation(grid, x, y, val):
    if val in grid[x]:
        # print("x"+str(grid[x]))
        return False
    elif True in [val == grid[i][y] for i in range(9)]:
        # print("y"+str(grid[:][y]))
        return False
    return True


def checkGrid(grid):
    if True in [0 in grid[i] for i in range(9)]:
        #print("grid has empty spots")
        return False
    rowmap = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
    colmap = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
    squmap = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if rowmap[grid[i][j]] == 0:
                rowmap[grid[i][j]] = 1
            else:
                return False
            if colmap[grid[j][i]] == 0:
                colmap[grid[j][i]] = 1
            else:
                return False
        rowmap = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
        colmap = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
    for i in [0, 3, 6]:
        for j in [0, 3, 6]:
            for tx in [0, 1, 2]:
                for ty in [0, 1, 2]:
                    if squmap[grid[i+tx][j+ty]] == 0:
                        squmap[grid[i+tx][j+ty]] = 1
                    else:
                        return False
            squmap = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
    return True


def find_empty_location(arr, l):
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            if(arr[row][col] == 0):
                l[0] = row
                l[1] = col
                return True
    return False


def solveSudoku(grid):
    if checkGrid(grid):
        return True
    else:
        l = [0, 0]
        if(not find_empty_location(grid, l)):
            return True
        i = l[0]
        j = l[1]

        for k in range(1, 10):
            if checkLocation(grid, i, j, k):
                grid[i][j] = k
                if solveSudoku(grid):
                    return True
                grid[i][j] = 0
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mydoku = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
              [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
              [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
              [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
              [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]

    codoku = [[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
              [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
              [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
              [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
              [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
              [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
              [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
              [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
              [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]]

    # print(checkLocation(mydoku, 1, 1, 2))
    # print(checkGrid(codoku))

    start = time.time()
    print(solveSudoku(mydoku))
    printgrid(mydoku)
    diff = time.time() - start

    print(diff)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know why your code is slow, *run it under a profiler*. For example `cProfile` that comes with Python.

I have saved your code as `mydoku.py`, and ran the following command:

```
python -m cProfile mydoku.py
```

This produced the following output:

```
True
True
5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2 
6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8 
1 9 8 3 4 2 5 6 7 
8 5 9 7 6 1 4 2 3 
4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1 
7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6 
9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4 
2 8 7 4 1 9 6 3 5 
3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9 
155.7312035560608
         186321197 function calls (173893648 primitive calls) in 155.731 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  155.731  155.731 mydoku.py:1(<module>)
111832944   35.234    0.000   61.143    0.000 mydoku.py:11(checkLocation)
 37205501   25.909    0.000   25.909    0.000 mydoku.py:15(<listcomp>)
 12427551    6.574    0.000   19.684    0.000 mydoku.py:21(checkGrid)
 12427551   13.110    0.000   13.110    0.000 mydoku.py:22(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 mydoku.py:4(printgrid)
12427550/1   74.904    0.000  155.731  155.731 mydoku.py:52(solveSudoku)
        1    0.000    0.000  155.731  155.731 {built-in method builtins.exec}
       94    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

If you look at the `tottime` column, this is the amount of time spent in a function *excluding* time in sub-function calls, while `cumtime` is the amount of time *including* sub-function calls.

Note how `solveSudoku` resursively calls itself more than 12 million times! Using a recursive call inside a triple-nested loop is bound to be inefficient.

The `solveSudoku` function itself takes about half of the total time. The functions that it calls take the rest.
Among those, the list comprehension in `checkLocation` is  slow.

In contrast, look at the profile of the geeksforgeeks code:

```
         119318 function calls (114341 primitive calls) in 0.079 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.079    0.079 geeksforgeeks.py:1(<module>)
     4979    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 geeksforgeeks.py:11(find_empty_location)
    44384    0.023    0.000    0.023    0.000 geeksforgeeks.py:21(used_in_row)
    13712    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 geeksforgeeks.py:28(used_in_col)
     6687    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 geeksforgeeks.py:35(used_in_box)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 geeksforgeeks.py:4(print_grid)
    44384    0.014    0.000    0.055    0.000 geeksforgeeks.py:43(check_location_is_safe)
   4979/2    0.011    0.000    0.079    0.040 geeksforgeeks.py:52(solve_sudoku)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 geeksforgeeks.py:78(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.079    0.079 {built-in method builtins.exec}
      183    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

I haven't looked at the algorithms in detail, but it is clear that the geeksforgeeks code uses several orders of magnitude less function calls.

Note that if you want more detailed information, I would suggest installing e.g. [`line-profiler`](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/).
As the name suggests, it can generate a profile for every line of code.

Comment: A big thanks to you for explaining how to figure out such things by oneself using a profiler, but really, @SumantAgnihotri 's answer specifically answered my query and also explained the concept of not using recursive calls within loops which was the main issue

Answer (score 1):

I modified `checkLocation` to look like this and it saved about 25% execution time:

```
def checkLocation(grid, x, y, val):
    if val in grid[x]:
        # print("x"+str(grid[x]))
        return False
    for i in range(9):
        if val == grid[i][y]:
            return False
    return True
```

Specifically this portion:

```
    elif True in [val == grid[i][y] for i in range(9)]:
        #print("y"+str(grid[:][y]))
        return False
```

has been replaced with:

```
    for i in range(9):
        if val == grid[i][y]:
            return False
```

The reason is that with the list comprehension, all 9 values are being checked every time, followed by another comparison.

The replacement loops through each value and does the comparison, returning False (as desired) as soon as the first true condition is met.

Comment: This is a really good point. One comment on my initial post mentioned using `any(list comprehension)` instead of `True in [list comprehension]` but that way you still check it all 9 times each time. Your method ditches those extra checks, so this is indeed an amazing catch.

However I cannot vouch for the same 25% reduction in time, maybe different CPUs had something to do with it.

Comment: I got 93.14125227928162 running your code and 69.46803832054138 with the edit just now.  Using i7 and running ubuntu in wsl

Comment: And 1.8658277988433838 using @Sumant Agnihotri's edit :)

Comment: Yeah I just retried it and used it in every place this `if True in [list comprehension]`  was used, and got a similar improvement. My bad, but I'm unable to edit that comment. I was able to find the culprit too, there isn't any proper 3x3 square checking code in my checkLocation function. Adding that brought it to sub 1 second.

Comment: Honestly, now on, I'm going to be using the method you mentioned everywhere whenever I see slow code (wherever applicable), it's pretty revolutionary for me and I have no idea why I never thought of that before. Kudos!